# other ways to write this markup

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Is there another way to write the preceding? The only difference is displaying it or not based on a condition.

Thanks,
rodchar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's another way, but I am not sure I like it better than the original ;)

```
<div id="myResults"<%= isTrue ? " style=\"display: none;\"" : "" %>>
```

If you want something that is both concise and readable, consider switching to the [NHaml view engine](http://code.google.com/p/nhaml/):

```
#myResults{ style = isTrue ? "display: none" : null }
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though Jörns example will work, you might want to consider putting this in an extension method:

```
<%= Html.Results(isTrue) %>
```

And in a class in your library:

```
public static class MyHtmlExtensions

    public static string Results(this HtmlHelper helper, bool hidden)
    {
        return String.Format("<div id=""myResults"" {0}>",
                             hidden = ? "style=""display: none;""" : "");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

since your using styles, you could get it out of the body of the html altogether...

```
<style type="text/css">
div#myResults { display: <$= isTrue ? "none" : "block" %>; }
</style>
...
<div id=myResults>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="myResults"<%= isTrue ? ' style="display: none;"' : '' %>>
```

Perhaps there's an even shorter notation.